# SessionFactory from EntityManager throws exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to get the Hibernate's SessionFactory from JPA's EntityManager with the following lines:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager manager;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    sessionFactory = manager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

But it throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface org.hibernate.SessionFactory; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface org.hibernate.SessionFactory
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418)
...

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface org.hibernate.SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.unwrap(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1489)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

What could be the reason for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `unwrap` to get session factory, you can use it go get the session.
From the session, you can get the factory if you need:

```
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory(); 
}
```

Comment: It worked! Now I'm getting an error " No CurrentSessionContext configured!", I guess I'm using it wrong then?