# SpringBoot 2.3.x -> 2.4.1: Cannot unwrap Session class anymore

Tags: spring-boot

After upgrading to Spring Boot 2.4.1. I get now an Exception

```
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134 and org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor are in unnamed module of loader 'app'
at at.myClass.core.StatusControllerBase.statusInfo(StatusControllerBase.java:89)
```

The matching code is

```
public class StatusControllerBase {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;
    ...
    public void doSomethingWithHibernate() {
            final SessionFactoryImplementor entityManagerFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) em
                    .unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class).getEntityManagerFactory();
```

Where the SpringBootApplication is located in a different project than the StatusControllerBase (`myStatusProject`). Any idea

- Why I get now the Exception?
- How to fix the Exception? I think I need configure something in the `pom` but have no clue what.

**UPDATE**

As Roar S. figured out correctly its the cast which fails. The main purpose why I need this is to retrieve the full URL for JDBC connection string. Or to be even more precise I'm finally interested in the DB host. The currently working code looks like:

```
final Session session = em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);

final SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();

final SessionFactoryImplementor entityManagerFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) em
            .unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class).getEntityManagerFactory();
final DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl connectionProvider = (DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl) entityManagerFactory
            .getServiceRegistry().getService(ConnectionProvider.class);
final String strUrl = ((HikariDataSource) connectionProvider.getDataSource()).getJdbcUrl().substring(5);
final URI uri = URI.create(strUrl);
ret.put("host", uri.getHost());
```

Comment: Hi. After some research around this, the error message is kind of misleading. Most likely, the error is that the cast to `SessionFactoryImplementor` fails. Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619707/14072498

Comment: Yeah... but to my knowledge this is the standard way to do so.  The main purpose to do so is to get the JdbcURL string. I see that the provided link works. but I have no clue to get the JdbcURL-string from the suggested link. I'll update the question.

Comment: Is it possible for you to inject the configuration instead? I guess the jdbc url is in the config somewhere? BR

Comment: Highly unclear how to do so...

Comment: If it's in application.yml or application.properties, I can most likely write the code you'll need. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion with OP, the intention of existing code is to retrieve host name from connection string. If connection string exists in application.properties, a more simple approach would be to do the following (replace `spring.datasource.url` with actual path to connection string within application.properties/application.yml):

```
public class StatusControllerBase {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManager em;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String datasourceUrl;

  ...
```

Comment: Thx for the update. I've figured it out as well. I think this approach/idea is which uses much less resources than my previous one.